# Vuejs3 - npm install The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL

Tags: npm, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a vuejs3 docker image, but as soon my docker file hits the `npm install` command I get the following error:

```bash
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
npm ERR! The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-20T18_50_33_592Z-debug-0.log
```

Here's is the package.json, case needed.

```json
{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host --port 8085",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@iconify/json": "^2.2.26",
    "@iconify/vue": "^4.1.0",
    "@mdi/font": "7.1.96",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.13.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pinia": "^2.0.23",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vuetify": "^3.1.6",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/tools": "^2.2.6",
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^0.8.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.47",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.14.4",
    "unplugin-icons": "^0.15.3",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.24.0",
    "vite": "^4.1.4",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-pwa-asset-generator": "^1.7.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.9"
  }
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error, apparently it's a package problem

Currently my @vue/cli version is: 5.0.8

Currently my node version is: v16.18.0

Currenlty my npm version is: 8.19.2

Comment: The `VOLUME` directives are unnecessary and will cause trouble, of note preventing the `RUN npm install` from having an effect; delete those.  The `ENTRYPOINT` line also makes it difficult to actually have the container run the server, and I'd delete that line and replace it with the thing you actually want the container to do, probably something like `CMD npm run start`.  Splitting the client and server into two separate images also might simplify the setup.

Comment: (You should not need volume mounts or `docker exec` shells in the typical course of running a container; the image should contain the complete application and its dependencies without external mounts, and running the container should run the server as the single foreground process on its own.)

Comment: This is just for the debug part. The release target  will not have it. 
The server code isn't the backend, It's just a node server, to serve the pages. I'm using node instead of nginx because I want to be able to override some environment variables.

Comment: also The entry point that I've defined there was just to test the docker file,  when it's finished this entry point will be removed.

Comment: I've edited the question, because the problem wasn't happening only in docker.

Comment: Please show the output of the log file: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-20T18_50_33_592Z-debug-0.log

Comment: @posixpascal Stackoverflow don't allow me to post the full content of the log file, so I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/4e9e03966e727f0ce50b731a549aa162)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found out the problem.

I don't know why, my project had a **yarn.lock** directory created.

Deleting this directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the logs alone I found the following issues:

```
33 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load /code/client [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
33 verbose shrinkwrap   errno: -21,
33 verbose shrinkwrap   code: 'EISDIR',
33 verbose shrinkwrap   syscall: 'read'
33 verbose shrinkwrap }
```

Along with a more detailed exception:

```
3872 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received null
3872 verbose stack     at open (node:internal/fs/promises:537:10)
3872 verbose stack     at writeFile (node:internal/fs/promises:876:20)
3872 verbose stack     at Shrinkwrap.save (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/shrinkwrap.js:1133:7)
3872 verbose stack     at [saveIdealTree] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:1445:33)
3872 verbose stack     at Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:176:31)
3872 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:146:5)
3872 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:134:5)
3873 verbose cwd /code/client
3874 verbose Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
3875 verbose node v18.14.2
3876 verbose npm  v9.5.0
3877 error code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
3878 error The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received null
3879 verbose exit 1
```

You said you were using `node 16` and `npm 8` but you are actually using `node 18` and `npm 9.5` as seen in the logs. Please check that these versions are compatible with your source code.

I would first try messing around with the Node and Npm versions either by changing the `Dockerfile FROM` or locally (https://github.com/tj/n this might help).

I've found a related issue here: https://onlyabug.com/issue/err-invalid-arg-type-when-upgrade-vue-2614-to-278-12692 but it wasn't solved.
Try downgrading your vue version to see the error disappears.

Comment: The node and npm version are the ones in my Pc. The ones in the log até from docker.

Comment: Then try using a different node base image for your dockerfile.

Comment: Using node 16.18 and 16.13 still presents the same problem.